# To what ring is $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y,Z]/(X-Y, X^3-Z)$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomial-rings, ring-isomorphism

**The problem:**
Let $(\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z],+,\cdot)$ be the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ in the variables $x$, $y$ and $z$ and the obvious operations $+$ and $\cdot$. Let $(x-y, x^3-z)$ be the ideal generated by $x-y$ and $x^3-z$. Find the ring to which $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/(x-y,x^3-z)$ is isomorphic.

A similar question has been asked before: [Which ring is $R[X,Y,Z,T]/(X-Y^2,T-Y^4,T^3-Z)$ isomorphic to?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3428440). Using the same approach, we set $x=y$ and $x^3=z$ and substitute for $y$ and $z$. Then we find $\mathbb{Z}[x,x,x^3]$ which is just $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. I'm trying to find out why this approach would work, i.e., formalise it in a proper proof. My idea is to use the first isomorphism theorem, but I get stuck near the end. I would very much appreciate if someone could help fill in this gap, check my proof for mistakes or provide additional (intuitive) information as to why the above method works.

**My proof:**
Consider the map $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z] \to \mathbb{Z}[x] : p(x,y,z) \mapsto p(x,x,x^3)$.

This is a homomorphism, since it obeys the relations $\varphi(p) + \varphi(q) = \varphi(p+q)$ and $\varphi(p) \cdot \varphi(q) = \varphi(p \cdot q)$ for all $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$ (verifying these is quite trivial).

Now take any $q \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and define a $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$ such that $p(x,y,z) = q(x)$. Since $\varphi(p(x,y,z)) = p(x,x,x^3) = q(x)$, $\varphi$ is surjective and it follows that $\mathbb{Z}[x] \subseteq \varphi(\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z])$. It is obvious that $\varphi(\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and, therefore, we must have $\varphi(\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]) = \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Lastly, we must show that $\ker(\varphi) = (x-y, x^3-z)$. For brevity's sake I will denote $I := (x-y,x^3-z).$
Let $p \in I$. Then there must exist $q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$ such that $p = q_1(x-y) + q_2(x^3-z)$. It follows that:
\begin{align*}\varphi(p(x,y,z)) &= \varphi(q_1(x,y,z)(x-y) + q_2(x,y,z)(x^3-z))\\ &= q_1(x,x,x^3)(x-x) + q_2(x,x,x^3)(x^3-x^3) = 0.\end{align*}
Thus $p \in \ker(\varphi)$ and $I \subseteq \ker(\varphi)$, since $p$ was chosen arbitrarily in $I$.
Now, take a $q \in \ker(\varphi)$. Then $\varphi(q(x,y,z)) = q(x,x,x^3) = 0$. *Somehow we must get that $q \in I$ so that we can conclude $\ker(\varphi) \subseteq I$ and thus $I = \ker(\varphi)$, but I seem to get stuck on every path. Proof by contradiction or by contraposition also seems fruitless. What am I missing?*

With all of the above, we may apply the first isomorphism theorem to conclude that:
$$\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/I = \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]/\ker(\varphi) \cong \varphi(\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]) = \mathbb{Z}[x]$$

Comment: A principal ideal has only one generator, so your ideal is not principal.

Comment: Does [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414281/show-kx-capy-x2-z-x3-0-in-kx-y-z-k-field/1415136#1415136) or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854588/ker-phi-x-1-a-1-x-n-a-n-for-a-ring-homomorphism-phi-rx-1) help? We can use the second link by writing $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y,Z] \cong (\mathbb{Z}[X])[Y,Z]$ and considering the evaluation map $\mathbb{Z}[X][Y,Z] \to \mathbb{Z}[X]$ that sends $Y \mapsto X, Z \mapsto X^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $q$ is congruent to $q(x,x,x^3)$ modulo $I$.

Comment: Nice hint! Maybe it also helps the OP to write $$q(x,y,z)= q(x,x-(x-y), x^3-(x^3-z)).$$

Comment: Your suggestion, @SeverinSchraven, was the shortcut I was hoping to find. Never did, though!

Comment: @Lubin I wouldn't know how to do it otherwise. Could you give me a hint how you would do it?

Comment: Sorry, @SeverinSchraven , I’m not going to embarrass myself by tell you the cracked-up strategy I was working on.

Comment: @Lubin i think we can learn something from every approach (I found also the deleted answer quite interesting). In any case, I wish you happy holidays :)

Comment: Continuing from that hint is relatively obvious. We must have $q(x,y,z) + I = q(x,x,x^3) + I = I$, hence $q \in I$. But how do you get to that point? I suppose @SeverinSchraven 's hint was supposed to help there. I can intuitively understand that the hint is true, though.

Comment: You can write $q(x,y,z)=\sum_{i,j,k=1}^n a_{ijk} x^i y^j z^k$ and then use my hint. Note that for $t>0$ we have, for example, $y^t = (x-(x-y))^t = x^t + g$ with $g\in (y-x)$.

Comment: I just figured it out as well, using the binomial theorem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Write $\mathbb{Z}[X]= R$ ring ( comm, $1$). If $a_1$, $\ldots$, $a_n$ are in $R$ then
the evaluation map at $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$,
$$f(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \mapsto f(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$$
from  $R[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$  to $R$ is surjective. Clearly the kernel contains the ideal $I= \langle X_1-a_1, \ldots, X_n - a_n\rangle$. In fact it equals $I$. Indeed, for every $f\in R[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ we have $f(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \equiv f(a_1, \ldots, a_n)  \mod I$, since $X_i \equiv a_i \mod I$ (@Thorgott:'s observation)- so  $f(a_1, \ldots, a_n) = 0$ iff $f(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \in \langle X_1-a_1, \ldots, X_n - a_n\rangle$, a multidimensional [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem).  We conclude that the evaluation map induces the isomorphism
$$R[X_1, \ldots, X_n]/\langle X_1-a_1, \ldots, X_n - a_n\rangle \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} R$$